# Conditional field selection with Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Say I have a collection of users with usernames and email addresses.

```
{ name: 'John Doe', email: 'john@doe.com', level: 5 }
{ name: 'Fred Foo', email: 'fred@foo.com', level: 2 }
{ name: 'Jo Green', email: 'jo@green.com', level: 5 }
{ name: 'Paul Bar', email: 'paul@bar.com', level: 3 }
```

I want to query this collection, selecting all users' names and levels. In Mongoose, I could do that like this:

```
User
  .find()
  .select('name level')
  .exec(callback)
```

This would give me the following:

```
{ name: 'John Doe', level: 5 }
{ name: 'Fred Foo', level: 2 }
{ name: 'Jo Green', level: 5 }
{ name: 'Paul Bar', level: 3 }
```

But if a user's level is above 4, I want to also get their email address. This would give me the following:

```
{ name: 'John Doe', email: 'john@doe.com', level: 5 }
{ name: 'Fred Foo', level: 2 }
{ name: 'Jo Green', email: 'paul@bar.com', level: 5 }
{ name: 'Paul Bar', level: 3 }
```

What is the best that with Mongo[ose]?

Comment: Either do 2 queries (one > 4 and the other <= 4), or just one query and delete/ignore fields that aren't relevant.

Comment: This is a (greatly) simplified version of what I'm actually trying to do. Writing the code to process it after the query would be a huge task. I'm hoping there's a way to it with mapReduce or the aggregation pipeline or something similar.

Comment: So what are you actually trying to do? Knowing this would help.

Answer (score 6):

No, there's not anyway in MongoDb currently to in one query to selectively return different sets of fields depending on conditions. A query in MongoDb and the associated projection applies to all documents.

A map reduce cannot do this (as a map reduce needs to return the same values for each document) and would be a poor fit. An aggregation isn't a general purpose alternative to many queries and returning fields conditionally would be complex.

You have a few options:

1. Execute multiple queries and merge the results. That would be very simple as each result is an array, so you could just merge the arrays.
2. Return the superset of all fields and filter in your app code.

I'd test the performance of the options. Neither are complex.

Answer (score 1):

As WiredPrairie stated, this is not possible within one query. It can be easily accomplished using aggregation and some app code. To return emails only with a level above 4, the following aggregation would work:

```js
User.aggregate().match({})
  .project({
    'name': 1,
    'email': {
      $cond: {
        if: {
          '$gt': ['$level', 4]
        },
        then: '$email',
        else: null
      }
    },
    'level': 1
  })
  .exec(callback);
```

Removing any null emails in the result set is straightforward with a utility library like lodash or underscore. In the callback function the following lodash functions will strip any null emails:

```js
var callback = function(err, users) {
  return _.map(users, function(user) {
    return _.omitBy(user, _.isNull);
  });
};
```